# Iterating over an std::vector two elements at a time plus last and first elements too

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate over a vector say {1,3,4,2} and collecting pairs basically (1,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,1). Collecting the first three pairs is easy but doing the last one is a bit difficult.

This is what I have:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<int>{1,3,4,2};
    auto vecOfPairs = std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>{};

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end() - 1; ++it)
    {
        auto a = *it;
        auto b = *(it+1);
        // DO some stuff with a and b
        vecOfPairs.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
    }

    auto front = v.front(); 
    auto back = v.back();
    // Do the same some stuff with front and back
    vecOfPairs.push_back(std::make_pair(back, front));

    for (const auto& pair : vecOfPairs)
        std::cout << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << '\n';

}
```

While this works, there is some code duplication (once I have the two values, I do some further calculations with those two values before making a pair and pushing it to the vectors. Is there a way to avoid this and just do the last operating in the same for loop?

Comment: I think the current code you have is what it should be. It's more clear to see what's happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler if you use plain subscripting. You can then add 1 and take the remainder with `% v.size()`:

```cpp
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    vecOfPairs.emplace_back(v[i], v[(i + 1) % v.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `i < v.size() - 1`?

Comment: @UserUsing No, that would not create a pair with the last element and the first.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want an indexed for-loop as in Ted's answer (and there are good reasons to avoid indexed for-loops), you can do something like:

```
for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    auto it2 = it + 1;
    if (it2 == v.end()) 
    {
        it2 = v.begin();
    }

    vecOfPairs.emplace_back(*it, *it2);
}
```

Comment: It can be oneliner: `vecOfPairs.emplace_back(*it, std::next(it) == v.end() ? v.begin() : std::next(it));`.

Comment: I'm curious about how this `for`-loop is less raw than the `for`-loop in my answer?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was incorrect with my terms. An iterator-based for-loop is still considered raw, I guess. I changed the wording from "raw" to "indexed". Thanks.

Comment: @cptFracassa Ok, I still don't see what benefit iterators bring over using the subscript operator here. Perhaps you could add an explanation to the answer? Right now I see _"there are good reasons to avoid indexed for-loops"_ - and I agree - but when followed by a similar loop, only with iterators, I have to wonder what makes that better in this particular case?